Tikz Border Problem
I am trying to create the figure below using Tikz.  It comes from Larson/Battaglia page 103 (see attached image).  I have started the picture, but I just don't know how to create the arrow at the end.  Is this something even possible?
Thank you in advance.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (4,2)node[draw,rounded corners,text width=6cm]{\textbf{\large{Connecting Representations}}.  \\ In Example 3, note that \(h\) has a nonremovable discontinuity at \(x=2\))};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (foo) [text width=6cm,inner sep=0.4cm]{\textbf{\large Connecting Representations.\\}   In Example 3, note that \(h\) has a nonremovable discontinuity at \(x=2\))};
        \draw [color=blue,path fading=north,ultra thick,orange!80!black] (foo.west)++(0,10pt) -- (foo.west);
        \draw[rounded corners,-{Latex[width=15pt,length=20pt]},ultra thick,orange!80!black] (foo.west) -- (foo.south west) -- (foo.south east) -- (foo.north east) -- (foo.north west) -- ++(-25pt,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you so much!

@NickB You're welcome!
